# Django user groups in template tag with single database hit

Tags: django, django-templates

How do I avoid multiple database calls in a template for a user's group(s).

I have hundreds of duplicate queries in views with tables that formats based on a user's group(s).

I can't rely on the default `user` in the template, as it does not (or I don't know how to) add the `prefetch_related` to get the user's group(s).  So I add to the view:

```
user = User.objects.all().select_related(
).prefetch_related(
    'groups',
).get(pk=request.user.pk)
```

In the template, if I want to check if a user is part of a group, I would do something like:

```
 {% if user|has_group:"Mechanic" %}
```

and make a template tag (I've tried multiple versions, but ultimately the template tag is not cached, and therefore will always hit the db again, even if it is using the user and its `prefetch_related` attributes)

```
@register.filter(name='has_group')
def has_group(user, group_name):
    lis = list(user.groups.all().values_list('name', flat=True))
    grp = get_object_or_404(Group, name=group_name)
    return grp in lis
```

If I pass all group objects to the template, I can avoid calls by checking the group type against the user model's `prefetch_related` attributes, but now I have to pass every group model individually to every view

in the view

```
  mechGroup = Group.objects.filter(name='Mechanic')
  managerGroup = Group.objects.filter(name='Manager')
  …
```

in the template

```
  {% if mechGroup in user.groups.all %}
```

Is there a better/simpler way to do this?

Comment: Use pickling https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#pickling-querysets

Comment: Can you explain in further detail?    I am not familiar with pickle, and it seems to create a file in addition to the template...  Do you pickle the user's groups on the view as well as each group?   I am confused as to even how to implement your suggestion of something I am just learning about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the prefetched groups, you have to avoid filtering the `groups.all()` queryset as this would create a new query. So:

```
def has_group(user, group_name):
    groups = user.groups.all()
    return group_name in [g.name for g in groups]
```

Note that this doesn't necessarily improve performance compared to a separate query per user. Be sure to do some profiling.

If you have thousands of calls to `has_group` per report, you can save the list of group names in a user attribute, shaving off another few ms per report:

```
def has_group(user, group_name):
    groups = user.groups.all()
    if not hasattr(user, 'group_names'):
        user.group_names = [g.name for g in groups]
    return group_name in user.group_names
```

And finally, if you know you'll be calling `has_user` for most users in the queryset, you can preinitialize the `group_names` attribute for all users to save the `has_group` function call on each query and use `if group_name in user.group_names` directly instead of `has_group(user, group_name)`.

I was surprised to see in an informal test run that while caching the list saved around 10% on 100.000 calls, inlining the membership query further saved a whopping 80%, bringing the total savings to an order of magnitude. But if you have only a few hundred calls per report, the effect is likely negligible.

One more way to save some time is making your prefetches leaner, because `prefetch_related` is a pretty heavy operation (which is why it often makes more sense to do targeted db queries rather than hauling all that data from the db into Python objects). So if you have a lot of users (or a lot of groups), and know you'll only need the group names rather than full-fledged group objects, don't use

```
users = User.objects.prefetch_related('groups')
```

Use this instead to get a list of `Group` objects rather than a `QuerySet`, with only the `name` field prefetched:

```
users = (User.objects
    .prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('groups',
                  queryset=Group.objects.only('name'), 
                  to_attr='group_list'
        )
    )
)
```

Then create the group names list as before:

```
for u in users:
    u.group_names = [g.name for g in u.group_list]
```

Unfortunately it's not yet (v2.1.5) possible to prefetch only the group names, e.g. by using `values_list` on the Prefetch object's queryset.

Comment: Care to explain the last statement further, please? 'To avoid recreating the list on every call, you can of course save the list of group names as a user attribute.'?

Comment: Updated the answer with details on caching and inlining.